# Passar coordenadas da Activity para o MapsFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Preciso passar a latitude e longitude que eu pego na `HomeActivity` para o `MapsFragment`, para o mapa abrir logo na posição do usuário.

Já tentei via `Intent` e não funciona.

Meu código:

***HomeActivity***

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private Button botaoPostar;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        botaoPostar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoPostarId);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, new MapsFragment(), "MapsFragment");
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            longi = location.getLongitude();
        } 
    }
}
```

***MapsFragment***

```
public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    double lat;
    double longi;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        //Pegando a latitude e longitude da HomeActivity
        LatLng minhaLocalizacao = new LatLng(lat, longi);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(minhaLocalizacao, 3));
    }
}
```

Seria possível?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Por que não obter a localização no *MapsFragment*?

Passe esse código

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
if (location != null) {
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    longi = location.getLongitude();
}
```

para dentro do método `onMapReady()`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        longi = location.getLongitude();
    } 

    LatLng minhaLocalizacao = new LatLng(lat, longi);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(minhaLocalizacao, 3));
}
```

**Notas:**

- Terá de construir o objecto `mGoogleApiClient`
- Terá de lidar com as permissões em tempo de execução se a *targetApi* for 23 ou superior.

No entanto a forma mais simples de ter a localização do dispositivo marcada no mapa é usar o método `setMyLocationEnabled()`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Apenas para fazer zoom - ver nota
    Location location = map.getMyLocation();

    if (location != null) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        longi = location.getLongitude();
    } 
    LatLng minhaLocalizacao = new LatLng(lat, longi);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(minhaLocalizacao, 3));
}
```

**Nota:**

- Terá de lidar com as permissões em tempo de execução se a *targetApi* for 23 ou superior.
- O método [getMyLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()) é considerado obsoleto, ele é usado aqui porque se pretende que a câmara faça *zoom* naquelas coordenadas. A [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#the_my_location_layer) sugere que o *zoom* deve ser feito pelo utilizador, usando o botão no canto superior do mapa.

Comment: na hora de implementar o mGoogleApiClient da erro no "this"   """mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)""" da erro nesse this, acredito que nao psossa usar isso num fragment, o que eu faço?

Comment: Em vez de `this` use `getActivity()`